# Are there metal clubs in London?

Tags: uk, london, nightlife

Are there any clubs/bars/pubs/etc in London that are only playing heavy metal (of any kind) ?

Comment: Yes, there are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists a list with ratings of Bars playing heavy metal on [viewlondon](http://www.viewlondon.co.uk/pubsandbars/heavy-metal-bars-in-london-recommended-London-525.html), [MetalTravelguide](http://www.metaltravelguide.com/europe/england/south-east/london) of course has an even larger one, and if you are looking for gigs you might want to check [rockandmetalgigs](http://www.rockandmetalgigs.co.uk/).

Comment: I can vouch that Garlic & Shots is good!

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee garlicandshots.com? How is that comment connected to anything?

Comment: @npst It's a bar that plays heavy metal. Londontown.com says "The music policy is dictated by the regulars, and they will go crazy, but if you love heavy metal too, you’ll have a fantastic night." http://www.londontown.com/LondonInformation/Bars_and_Clubs/Garlic__Shots/6f5b/